# Using VFP to submit credit card transactions to Paypal via NVP or SOAP?

Tags: paypal

I know this is a longshot, but does anybody have any VFP (Visual FoxPro) samples of submitting credit card transactions to paypal pay flow pro API using NVP or SOAP? All of the samples from paypal are in C#, vb.net, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of [building an HTTP POST with VFP](http://www.example-code.com/foxpro/http_post_form.asp).

```
LOCAL loHttp
LOCAL lnSuccess
LOCAL loReq
LOCAL loResp

loHttp = CreateObject('Chilkat_9_5_0.Http')

*  Any string unlocks the component for the 1st 30-days.
lnSuccess = loHttp.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial")
IF (lnSuccess <> 1) THEN
    ? loHttp.LastErrorText
    RELEASE loHttp
    CANCEL
ENDIF

loReq = CreateObject('Chilkat_9_5_0.HttpRequest')

*  Add the request params expected by the server-side:
loReq.AddParam("city","Paris")
loReq.AddParam("country","France")

*  Send the POST  (This is a real URL that may be tested.)

loResp = loHttp.PostUrlEncoded("http://www.chilkatsoft.com/httpTest/cityCountry.asp",loReq)
IF (ISNULL(loResp)) THEN
    ? loHttp.LastErrorText
    RELEASE loHttp
    RELEASE loReq
    CANCEL
ENDIF

RELEASE loResp

*  The exact HTTP request sent and response received
*  by the example code above is as follows:


/*


---- Sending ----
POST /httpTest/cityCountry.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: www.chilkatsoft.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 25

city=Paris&country=France
---- Received ----
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 09 Dec 2009 16:16:00 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 156
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDQCDTSSAC=MHJCNFMDENFOKGINOFEDILCM; path=/
Cache-control: private


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</head>
<body>

France<br />Paris<br />

</body>
</html>

*/


RELEASE loHttp
RELEASE loReq
```

You should be able to work from that and turn it into a call to PayPal.  You just need to change the endpoint URL to PayPal's and then add all your parameters for whatever call you're making.

You can use [PayPal's API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/) to see what parameters are available for any call you want to make.

Comment: I added the code snippet from the first link here, but the link to the PayPal reference is pretty general.  The original post wasn't asking for any specific API.